# Keep the camera activated while using other apps during a video conference

Tags: ipad, video, camera, facetime, ipados

When I am in a videoconference with any app (I have tested with zoom, facetime, discord and skype), if I change to another app my friend stops seeing my camera.

My issue is that I use the iPad to have zoom meetings where I share the screen and I move through the iPad and I need to keep the camera working while using other apps.

Is it possible to achieve this using any other app or changing some configuration in the iPad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is unfortunately not possible in any other app or by changing settings in the iPad.

Apple has explicitly forbidden apps to record videos while they are in the background, and iOS prevents this from happening.

As Apple writes [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesessioninterruptionreason/avcapturesessioninterruptionreasonvideodevicenotavailableinbackground?preferredLanguage=occ) for app developers:

"Camera usage is prohibited while in the background."

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the [AV Developer Kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/accessing_the_camera_while_multitasking), it is possible beginning with iOS 16, but the app has to explicitly support it:

> Camera access is usually limited to apps running in full-screen mode. If your app enters a multitasking mode like Split View, the system disables the camera. Starting in iOS 16, your app can use the camera while multitasking by setting the isMultitaskingCameraAccessEnabled property to true on supported systems. Enabling this behavior also extends to Picture in Picture mode using AVKit. See Adopting Picture in Picture for video calls to learn more.